# How to echo an input of an textarea with line breaks?

Tags: php, html, textarea

I'm using an textarea to send text to my DB.

Screenshot of db:

[image]

When I'm reading from the DB it removes the line breaks, how can I keep them in $row['opmerkingen']?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove line breaks (no characters!) from the string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

When displaying text, use [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net/nl2br) to convert newlines to `<br/>` tags, i.e., instead of `<?php echo $row['text']; ?>`, use `<?php echo nl2br($row['text']); ?>`.

By default, browsers display newlines as spaces, therefore they have to be converted to `<br/>` tags.

---

For those who find this useful - please consider using `white-space: pre-line`, suggested by Emil Vikström. I'm not a web guy anymore and easily can't verify this, but Boaz says in comments that it is supported by all modern browsers. If so, that should be preferred to using `nl2br()`.

Comment: Just what i was looking for

Answer (score 23):

An alternative to nl2br is to make use of the CSS attribute [white-space](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-white-space):

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Comment: +1 IMHO `nl2br()` *is* the alternative. Styling and formatting should be handled by CSS only, now that [all modern browsers support the `pre-line` value of the `white-space` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Answer (score 8):

I put as follows but **not working with single quotes**.

```
echo $row['text'].'\n';
```

Put the **double quotes**. Then worked.

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="62" style="white-space: pre-line;" wrap="hard">
<?php echo $row['text']."\n"; ?>
</textarea>
```

When we getting data it is comming with **\r\n**. Also use the **double quotes** there.